# Hook before user is created and make some custom validation

Tags: customization, hooks, user-registration, validation

I try to hook in user creation process in admin dashboard `/wp/wp-admin/user-new.php` to make some custom validation on data with the following hook, but the hook is not executed on form submit. What goes wrong in this case?

What I want, I have a custom ACF relation field which should be mandatory only if the selected role is editor. So I want to parse the request and check against the rules. If it fails than do not create the user return the custom error message.

```
add_action( 'register_post', function($user_login, $user_email, $errors) {
    var_dump('test');
    die;

    $userIsValid = ValidateUser::make($errors);

    if(!$userIsValid) {
        $errors->add( 'bad_email_domain', '<strong>ERROR</strong>: errors' );
    }
});
```

Comment: There's a lot of missing information and context here, can you update your question to include the form, add some context for what `ValidateUser` is and what is inside `ValidateUser::make`, or why you're hooking into `register_post`? Use the `Edit` link to add more details to your question

Comment: Hi @TomJNowell I just made  an update on post

Comment: ah I see, keep in mind that you can't ask about the ACF part here as 3rd party plugin dev support questions are offtopic here, but a general how to run code before a user has been created and block the creation could be asked. It's definitely not `register_post` though, users are not posts.

Comment: As per documentation seems like to be used before a user is created https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/register_post/ . Can you please give some tips which hooks are appropriate to use for this scenario?

Comment: @TomJNowell I just checked and `register_post` is indeed inside the `register_new_user` function (great naming huh).

Comment: @fefe If your validation is dependent on ACF custom fields for a new user, the new user doesn't yet exist so you can't check using standard ACF field functions - you'll need to check the corresponding `$_POST` values instead.

Comment: yes I would use the `$_REQUEST` bag, but `register_post` is not getting fired

Comment: @fefe I have just checked and `register_post` only fires for user registrations via the WordPress login page. You should use the [`user_profile_update_errors`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/user_profile_update_errors/) hook instead.

Comment: can't you do that with some basic js tho ? something that would add an event on your select option which would trigger  myDOM.required=true.

Comment: thanks @TheDeadMedic I will check

Comment: @TheDeadMedic seems to work, I will need to make more testings  on it but for now works

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add `, 10, 3` after your closure to set the hook priority and (more importantly) [the number of accepted arguments](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_action/) - otherwise `$user_email` and `$errors` will not be passed.

```php
add_action( 'register_post', function ( $user_login, $user_email, $errors ) {
    $userIsValid = ValidateUser::make($errors);

    if(!$userIsValid) {
        $errors->add( 'bad_email_domain', '<strong>ERROR</strong>: errors' );
    }
}, 10, 3 );
```

**Update**: The `register_post` hook only fires inside `register_new_user()`, which is only used for user registration via the WordPress login page.

To handle errors within the admin (i.e. Users > Add New) use the [`user_profile_update_errors`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/user_profile_update_errors/) hook instead.

Comment: thank you for your feedback, seems not to be triggered on user creation even with the closures